# Date operations in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run this queries (Oracle 12c):

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - '25-SEP-18' FROM dual;

SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE trunc(sysdate) = '04-SEP-19';

CREATE TABLE my_table (order_date date);
INSERT INTO my_table (order_date) VALUES ('04-SEP-19');
```

I expect implicit conversion and everything is good with the 2 last queries, but for the first i get error ORA-01722: invalid number. NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR'. What is the problem?

Comment: You haven't supplied a date to subtract from a date in the first query; my guess is that Oracle expects the value being extracted to be a number, unless it's explicitly a date. `25-SEP-18` can't be converted to a number.

Comment: TRUNC (in this case) truncated date to the nearest day, but it's still date.

Comment: Yes, the `trunc(sysdate)` is a date, but the `'25-SEP-18'` is a string, not a date. It's this that I think Oracle tries to convert to a number rather than a date.

Comment: As you can substract a DATE or a NUMBER from a DATE, Oracle doesn't know which one to convert, so I guess it takes TO_NUMBER.

Comment: Boneist and btpys, thanks for your help! You were right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is WHY is does not work? I didn't find any explanations in documentation.

The documentation has a section on [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) which explains what is allowed. The [table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) shows that arithmetic is only allowed between dates, timestamp, intervals and numbers. When you do:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - '25-SEP-18'
```

you are trying to subtract a *string* from a date, which isn't possible. Oracle 'helpfully' tries anyway and interprets the string as a number, effectively doing:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - to_number('25-SEP-18')
```

which understandably throws the error you see, "ORA-01722: invalid number". As already said, you should explicitly convert your string to a date:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - to_number('25-SEP-18', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

or preferably with a four-digit year, and since you're using a month name it's safer to specify the language that is in:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - to_number('25-SEP-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

or more simply, if it's a fixed value, with [a date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1):

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - DATE '2018-09-25'
```

---

> I expect implicit conversion

You should not rely on implicit conversion, particularly where that is influenced by session NLS settins. As well as the date language I already mentioned, someone else running your statement could have a different `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting which could lead to errors or more subtle data mismatches or corruption; e.g.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

SELECT trunc(sysdate) - DATE '2018-09-25' FROM dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)-DATE'2018-09-25'
-------------------------------
                            344

SELECT trunc(sysdate) - to_date('25-SEP-18') FROM dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TO_DATE('25-SEP-18')
-----------------------------------
                             730831

SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE trunc(sysdate) = '04-SEP-19';

no rows selected

CREATE TABLE my_table (order_date date);
INSERT INTO my_table (order_date) VALUES ('04-SEP-19');
```

The second query gets a much bigger value than expected; and the third gets no rows back from dual.

Looking at the implicitly converted date shows you why:

```
SELECT to_char(order_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM my_table;

TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'
--------------------
 0019-09-04 00:00:00
```

With a `YYYY` mask (and no `FX` modifier) a 2-digit year value like 19 is converted as 0019, not 2019. That sort of problem could go unnoticed for some time, giving you incorrect results in the meantime.

If the session's format mask had `RRRR` or - as you have - `RR` then it would be interpreted as 2019; but the point is that you usually have no control over the settings in another session that runs your code later.

You can also cause performance issues or errors by creating [implicit conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694) where you didn't expect, or where they behave in a way you didn't expect. Not in this example - "When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts the character data to DATE" - but it still comes up. It's better to avoid the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with strings with dates in them you should use the to TO_DATE command, otherwise Oracle may not always figure out that the string contains a date.

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) - TO_DATE('25-SEP-18') FROM dual;
```

Even better is to indicate the format of the date within the string

```
  SELECT trunc(sysdate) - TO_DATE('25-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is an obvious solution and i know about this. The question is WHY is does not work? I didn't find any explanations in documentation.

Comment: @HereGoes even better would be to supply four digit years; Y2K may be a distant event to some, but we didn't go through it to use two digit years afterwards! *{;-)